# Does customers usually allow third party applications in their Onpremise hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

We are building a solution to validate the data migrated from traditional RDBMS to on-premise hadoop and also perform validation of the data after the migration.The scripts performing the validation will compare the data between hadoop and data present on-premise.I would like to know if customers would allow our application script inside the cluster or we have to execute the scirpts from a remote server where our application will be hosted?

Comment: Who is your "customer"? Why wouldn't they allow it? Why don't you ask them?

Comment: Actually we are trying to build a generic solution.We are not aware whether the third party applications are generally allowed inside clusters in actual implementations.So before starting we wanted to check what standards are generally followed in the industry..

Comment: "third party applications are generally allowed inside clusters" ... Yes. Lots of external tools are used after the installation of any of HDP, CDH, or MapR, which I would recommend any of those over standard installation of Hadoop. For example, I personally use Elasticsearch to index log files rather than the built-in variants of Solr

Answer (score 0):

> data migrated from traditional RDBMS to on-premise hadoop

Using what tools? Sqoop? Spark? Kakfa? NiFi?

Each one of those tools are installed on the side of your Hadoop cluster, so in that case, yes they are "installable". Whether they are "allowed" is up to your Hadoop Administrator / Architects.

You won't get "24/7 vendor support" if you use a tool you aren't paying for, though.

Comment: No we are looking at custom scripts that we are creating to perform some validations in the data in hadoop. I was wondering whether such scripts can be hosted inside the cluster?

Comment: Hosted how? Why are you under the impression that  they cannot be? If the scripts are already on some computer, Hadoop won't interfere with them. The operating system is still there... You can move the scripts wherever they need to run